# Matplotlib timeseries plot with groupby function applied to df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, time-series

Currently I have this df with eight different speakers. :

```
                      raw_score
  Speaker date                 
  Allison 2012-10-31   0.796908
          2012-11-30   1.792649
          2012-12-31   0.668619
  Warsh   2015-03-31        NaN
          2015-04-30        NaN
          2015-05-31  -0.094364
          2015-06-30   0.349691
```

I used this code to created my current df:

```
dropped = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'text'], axis=1)
dropped['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(dropped['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
dropped.index = dropped['date']
del dropped['date']
dropped = dropped.groupby('Speaker')
dropped = dropped.resample('M').mean()
```

I would like to make a timeseries graph with 'raw_score' on the y-axis and date (currently the index of the df) on the x-axis with a seperate line on the graph for each speaker.

I have tried the following, but do not get what I want:

```
dropped.plot()
```

[image: New graph!]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [47]: df.reset_index(level=0).pivot_table(index='date', columns='Speaker', values='raw_score')
Out[47]:
Speaker      Allison     Warsh
date
2012-10-31  0.796908       NaN
2012-11-30  1.792649       NaN
2012-12-31  0.668619       NaN
2015-03-31       NaN       NaN
2015-04-30       NaN       NaN
2015-05-31       NaN -0.094364
2015-06-30       NaN  0.349691


In [48]: df.reset_index(level=0).pivot_table(index='date', columns='Speaker', values='raw_score').plot()
Out[48]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc804710>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to include the graph your code produced! Is there a way for me to add smoothing, move the legend, and add a zero line? Thanks!

Comment: I like this answer, and want to accept it. Just want to make the graph look a little prettier first :p

Comment: @GrahamStreich, i think [Scott Boston has already fulfilled all your wishes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46593799/5741205) - didn't he? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
ax = df.unstack(0)['raw_score'].plot()
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
_ = ax.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=.7)
_ = ax.set_ylabel('Raw Score')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: @GrahamStreich What sort of smoothing do you want to apply?

Comment: ax = df.rolling('360D').mean().plot()

Comment: how do I incorporate this `ax = df.rolling('360D').mean().plot()` into the graph? thanks!